# gcloud app deploy fails "cannot import internal package"

Tags: google-app-engine, go, gcloud

I am compiling a GO app that I want to upload and run on the Google Cloud Platform. I am importing the `appengine/datastore` package and am running into problems with vendoring of the packages. Since I want to provide stable builds I want to have as much of the dependencies vendored in my source tree, but when I vendor `appengine/datastore` I run in to problems runnning `gcloud app deploy`:

OperationError: Error Response: [9] Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: Compile failed:
2017/09/19 01:07:31 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: package "vendor/google.golang.org/appengine/search" cannot import internal package "google.golang.org/appengine/internal/search"

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: Compile failed:
2017/09/19 01:07:31 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: package "vendor/google.golang.org/appengine/search" cannot import internal package "google.golang.org/appengine/internal/search"
```

I can run the `dev_appserver.py` script just fine, the application runs smoothly locally, and `go test` succeeds compiling and running all the module tests.

If I try to remove the vendoring of any of the appengine packages and instead use `go get` to install them outside of the version control, `dev_appserver.py` no longer runs, complaining about duplicate packages:

```
rm -rf ../vendor/google.golang.org/appengine
go get google.golang.org/appengine
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
[....]
2017/09/19 10:20:10 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: package "golang.org/x/net/context" is imported from multiple locations: "/home/peter/src/myproject/go/src/myproject/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context" and "/home/peter/src/myproject/go/src/golang.org/x/net/context"
```

while `gcloud app deploy` instead complains about not finding the packages at all:

```
[...]
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                             
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: Compile failed:
Compile failed:
2017/09/19 01:22:13 go-app-builder: build timing: 7×compile (1.749s total), 0×link (0s total)
2017/09/19 01:22:13 go-app-builder: failed running compile: exit status 2
myproject/vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm/normalize.go:15: can't find import: "golang.org/x/text/transform"
$ find .. -name transform
../vendor/golang.org/x/text/transform
```

**EDIT**: *WORKAROUND*: I have found that I can make it compile with `gcloud` by symlinking the vendored directories (`github.com` and `golang.org`) into the application directory (`ln -s ../vendor/* .`), and downloading the appengine package manually (`go get google.golang.org/appengine`). However, I need to delete the symlinks to be able to run `dev_appserver.py`, so this is not nearly optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because of how App Engine builds Go apps.

Because of the App Engine standard environment [security sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/runtime#Go_The_sandbox) and container model, they prohibit Go code from importing any packages which could potentially mess with their systems--like `unsafe`, for instance. They also block direct imports of the internal appengine packages (`google.golang.org/appengine/internal/whatever`) for the same reason.

For this project, you've locally vendored your dependencies. For the app engine app builder, though, this looks no different then if you had just made another sub-package in your app and put the dependencies in there. It's functionally the same as if you had just copied and pasted `appengine/search` straight into your project.

Because `appengine/search` imports its corresponding internal package, `appengine/internal/search`, and the Go app builder doesn't really differentiate between what's in your application code and what's in your `vendor` directory, it fails the build. To App Engine, it looks like *you* imported `appengine/internal/search`, which is prohibited by the security model. It doesn't know how `appengine/internal/search` is being used, because it doesn't control what's in `vendor`, so to keep the sandbox secure it doesn't let you import it.

The solution to this problem is, basically, to not vendor your dependencies.

If you remove all the `appengine/whatever` packages from `vendor`, then the App Engine builder will look for them on Google's build servers instead of in your project. The App Builder trusts its own local copies of the `appengine` libraries not to misbehave, so they're permitted to import `appengine/whatever/internal` packages.

(As an aside, if you haven't already, make sure `gcloud` and all related components are up to date. This can sometimes resolve gnarly dependency issues)

Comment: That explains the deploy case very well, thank you. The problem is that I cannot get appserver to run locally *without* vendoring the libraries, I would like to find a way to be able to run both without messing with symlinking and moving stuff around.

Comment: I had this problem before--I remember one particularly janky solution was to `go get` the dependencies directly into appengine's local `$GOROOT`. I think, though, what ultimately fixed it for me was an update to `gcloud` and all components.

Comment: If you use cloudbuild to deploy your app vendoring is OK